# I want to draw this exact heart with paths in SVG in HTML5 and I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Tags: html, svg

This is the heart I'm trying to draw:

[image]

Here's the code I've written:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html/>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SVG Paths</title>
</head>
<body>
    <svg width="200px" height="200px">
        <pattern id="rulerPattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10"
            viewBox="0 0 10 10" >
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="10" y2="0" 
                stroke="gray" fill="none" />
            <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="10" 
                stroke="gray" fill="none"/>
        </pattern>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"
            fill="url(#rulerPattern)" stroke="black" />

        <path d="M 100 180 20 80 C20 80 60 -15 100 80"
    stroke="black" 
    stroke-width="5"
    fill="red" />
        <path d="M 100 180 180 80 C180 80 140 -15 100 80"
    stroke="black" 
    stroke-width="5"
    fill="red" />

    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to get the exact shape of the heart shown on the first picture using paths.

Answer (score 4):

The given svg specifies the semi-circles of the heart's top with the `C` subcommand of the `path` element. This subcommand creates a cubic spline which is ill-suited to the purpose since no segments of circles can be drawn with this family of curves (more about splines can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics))).

The following code rectifies the svg definition:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SVG Paths</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg width="200px" height="200px">
            <pattern id="rulerPattern" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
                x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10"
                viewBox="0 0 10 10" >
                <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="10" y2="0" 
                    stroke="gray" fill="none" />
                <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="10" 
                    stroke="gray" fill="none"/>
            </pattern>
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"
                fill="url(#rulerPattern)" stroke="black"
            />

            <path
                d="M 180,80 L100,180 20,80 A 40,40 0,0,1 100,80 A 40,40 0,0,1 180,80"
                stroke="black" 
                stroke-width="5"
                fill="red"
            />
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

The icon can be drawn with a single path. This path consists of a polyline to generate the lower portion of the heart and two adjacent semi-circles.

The syntax for the path definition is outlined in the [svg specs at W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html). The complex part is the specification of the semi-circles which employ the elliptic arc command whose usage is detailed [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands).

NB: The `DOCTYPE` element is not an xml/html element, it closes without `/`.